# mapping payload with json object in dataweave

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, anypoint-studio

What I'm trying to do is map the CodeOT to each object in my payload such as :

null/0 get the value 1
1 to 5 get the value 2
and 6 to 9 get the value 3

I am lost in how to do it as I'm new to dataweave

example of payload :

```
    {
    "refSig" : "0110443372",
    "indSap":2
    },
    {
    "refSig" : "0000443942",
    "indSap":0
    },
    {
    "refSig" : "0117243942",
    "indSap":null
    }
```

the conversion table is provided and must be used as is, here's a part of it

```
{
    "CodeSap": null,
    "Libelle": "",
    "CodeOT": 1
  },
  {
    "CodeSap": 0,
    "Libelle": "Elle a demandé un délai de paiement",
    "CodeOT": 1
  },
  {
    "CodeSap": 1,
    "Libelle": "Elle a des factures SATD",
    "CodeOT": 2
  },
  {
    "CodeSap": 2,
    "Libelle": "Elle a des factures remises à l’huissier",
    "CodeOT": 2
  }
```

I need to map the CodeOT from the conversion table to the indSap from the payload using CodeSap

I started doing this but it doesn't seem to lead me anywhere

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---

lignesOK : payload map (item, index) -> {
      bf: item mapObject (value, key) -> {
      (key): value,
      codeOt: varTable map (it,val) ->{
          (val):(it)
      }
      }
}
```

expected output for the example of the payload above is :

```
{
    "refSig" : "0110443372",
    "CodeOT":2
    },
    {
    "refSig" : "0000443942",
    "CodeOT":1
    },
    {
    "refSig" : "0117243942",
    "CodeOT":1
    }
```

Comment: All the samples are invalid JSON. Are all of them arrays? How is indSap == 7 mapped since it is not in the 'table'?

Comment: These are not the complete json objects, I copied a part of them for example purposes.

Comment: You should provide the part of the table needed to get a consistent output then and they should be valid JSON at the least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the input and table are arrays and that entries in the table are unique per `CodeSap` the following script works, though the output is a bit different than expected because of the incomplete table provided:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var varTable=[{
    "CodeSap": null,
    "Libelle": "",
    "CodeOT": 1
  },
  {
    "CodeSap": 0,
    "Libelle": "Elle a demandé un délai de paiement",
    "CodeOT": 1
  },
  {
    "CodeSap": 1,
    "Libelle": "Elle a des factures SATD",
    "CodeOT": 2
  },
  {
    "CodeSap": 2,
    "Libelle": "Elle a des factures remises à l’huissier",
    "CodeOT": 2
  }]
---
payload map (item, index) -> {
      
      refSig: item.refSig,
      codeOt: (varTable filter (item.indSap == $.CodeSap))[0].CodeOT
}
```

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "refSig": "0110443372",
    "codeOt": null
  },
  {
    "refSig": "0000443942",
    "codeOt": 1
  },
  {
    "refSig": "0117243942",
    "codeOt": 1
  }
]
```

Comment: It actually worked thank you Aled, I did mention that null and0 get the value 1/// 1 to 5 get the value 2 /// 6 to 9 get the value 3

Comment: The explanation is confusing because it would be easy to provide a solution without using the table and the relationship to those rules was somewhat unclear.

Comment: I tried my best to edit it